# Test message to BizTalk Services

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, biztalk, biztalk-services

I've deployed a BizTalk Service project to Azure. I'm able to connect to the service in the [Azure BizTalk Service Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f75a6a6-a54e-44eb-8b11-1b5ea8928754) but I cannot seem to pass a successful request test message to the XML One Way Bridge via the "Send Test Message" command in the Azure BizTalk Service Explorer.

When I click the "Send Test Message" command, the window prompts me for a test request message, but whatever I send always comes back with an error. Here is an example test message I'm trying to send:

```
<ns1:Select xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/TestBizTalk">
<ns1:TestBizTalk xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo">
<ns1:Columns>*</ns1:Columns>
<ns1:Query>where TestBizTalkID = 1</ns1:Query>
</ns1:TestBizTalk>
</ns1:Select>
```

That query will result in an error message "Filename is required." The xml request appears to follow SQL Server Adapter schema for issuing a SELECT statement, but it's returning the filename error, and I'm not able to find an BizTalk project or service artifact that's missing a filename parameter.

My questions are, is my test message format incorrect? And if so, is there a way of finding out what "Filename" is missing?